# Windows: Kill processes by arguments

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, process

I'm on Windows 10. I want to kill all processes that have the word "foobar" in their command line arguments. How can I do that in the terminal, without touching the mouse?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: [Get Process List with Command Line Arguments - Security Boulevard](https://securityboulevard.com/2020/01/get-process-list-with-command-line-arguments/) is a starting point for you.